# Security of natural Windows 7, 8.1 or 10 behind no firewall

Tags: windows

I've often been wondering today in 2016 how secure is truly an up-to-date natural Windows 7, Windows 8.1 or Windows 10 OS on internet behind no firewall other than its internal windows firewall.

Is this common practise to do or is it strongly recommended to buy an alternate software firewall on top of it or absolutely put it behind a hardware firewall ?

Answer (score 2):

TL;TR: it is not safe and if local or hardware firewalls can help depends on how deep they can inspect.

It depends on your exact environment but the currently the major attacks against PC's are delivered via web and mail. This includes [drive-by downloads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive-by_download), [malvertising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malvertising), malware inside phishing mails (like alleged invoices or delivery notices) and other social attacks (like [scareware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scareware) or "you need to install this flash update before viewing this video") etc.

An traditional packet filter firewall like employed in the normal SoHo routers or what is built into windows will not be able to detect these kind of attacks, because filtering is only done at the transport layer but one needs application layer inspection to detect these attacks. It does not matter if this is a "software" or "hardware" firewall, but it depends on the capabilities.

More protection provide endpoint security solutions which include antivirus to detect malware hopefully before it gets executed and blacklists either built into the browser (like Google Safe Browsing or Microsoft Smart Screen) or within a local web proxy. Similarly the better corporate firewalls (NGFW, UTM, IPS, Secure Gateway...) are able to do deeper inspection and claim to provide similar protection. Note that none of the solutions offers full protection and that the claims of the vendors about the protection they offer are often only loosely related to the reality (Often the claims or more detached from reality the cheaper the products are).

Apart from malware or phishing attempts to steal authorization credentials (typically for banks, Paypal or similar) you have attacks which use design problems of the current web. These includes [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attacks for example to [reconfigure local routers](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2012/10/01/hacked-routers-brazil-vb2012/) or [XSS attacks](http://businessinsights.bitdefender.com/-ebay-xss-security-flaw-or-how-criminals-phish-your-customers-passwords) to steal authorization credentials. These need even deeper inspection of the content and chances are low that a corporate firewall at the perimeter will detect these attacks when directed against the local intranet, because in this case the attack is from inside the local network (clients browser) to another host in the local network, even if the attacker itself is outside.

Answer (score 1):

I have free Avira installed on Windows8.1, Avira uses Windows firewall. Till know I haven't encountered any trouble related to virus or malware. This doesn't mean my laptop is totally safe. 
Even if I have the strongest known AV and firewall, that doesn't mean my laptop will be totally safe, either.

Using the native Windows firewall or an external firewall depend on how critical is the software and data that reside on your machine, and what the consequences that can be tolerated or not after the firewall failed to stop a remote attack.